# How to include global styles in custom angular library

Tags: angular, sass, scss-mixins, angular-library

I have a running Angular 7 application and I am trying to create custom control library.I have some global styles that needs to be imported into the Angular application from this control library.

I am trying to achieve something like the following:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

in the consumer application where this control library will be used. I have a root style sheet which imports other mixins as shown below:

**root.scss**

```
      @include list-themeable($theme);
      @include radiobutton-themeable($theme);
      @include checkbox-themeable($theme);
```

I need to compile this root.scss file during the library build to create a css file that could be imported in the consumer application where this library will be used.

I googled for the solution and came across [Compiling css library in Angular 6](https://medium.com/@Dor3nz/compiling-css-in-new-angular-6-libraries-26f80274d8e5):

- Install some devDependencies in our library in order to bundle the
  css:

  ```
   ng-packagr 
   scss-bundle 
   ts-node
  ```
- Create a css-bundle.ts
- Add _theme.scss inside the /src directory of the library that 
  actually contains and imports all the css that we want to bundle.
- Add postbuild npm script to run the css-bundle.ts:
- Include it in the styles tag in your Application in the angular.json

Is there any other way to do it..?

Please help me on this.

Comment: This is the way, as far as I know , what bothers you with this strategy?